# Are Kotlin suspend functions blocking?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, suspend

Code:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() {
    println("main start")
    f1()
    println("main end")
}

suspend fun f1() {
    println("f1 start")
    delay(2_000)
    println("f1 end")
}
```

Actual Output:

```
main start
f1 start
f1 end
main end
```

My expected output

```
main start
f1 start
main end
f1 end
```

Does this mean `suspend` functions are blocking unlike JS?

Comment: What gave you the impression that you would get the second output? Kotlin suspend functions are part of Kotlin’s coroutine support - the unique selling point is that it makes asynchronous code _seem to_ act like synchronous code.

Comment: I dont understand how this is non blocking. 
Isnt this blocking? Execution waits for 2s in `f1()` before printing `main end`.
My understanding of non blocking is that execution does not wait for anything. As soon as execution sees `delay` it moves to the next available instruction which is `println("main end")`

Comment: Execution waits. The thread doesn’t. That’s the whole point of structured concurrency. It is best modelled and understood as callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default behavior read more about suspending functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html), if you want to run `f1` asynchronously you have to use `async` as:

```
suspend fun main() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        println("main start")//Run in main
        val getF1 = async(Dispatchers.IO) { f1() } // Run f1 in IO
        println("main end") // Run in main
        println(getF1.await())//Run in main
    }
}

suspend fun f1() : String {
    println("f1 start")
    delay(2_000)
    println("f1 end")
    return "f1 result"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes it clear. 
I misunderstood because I assumed that each suspend function creates its own coroutine.
But in fact in my code only one coroutine is created.